# Zend application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'd prefer to use native php for Zend configuration.
How would I convert this Zend application.ini segment into php?

```
[development : production]
```

production section supposedly inherits from development section.
P.S we are talking about ZEND framework here.

**Update:** Looks like I wasn't clear with my question.

All I wanted to know was how Zend_Application handles inheritance/nesting in php options file comparing to ini or xml.

**INI config example** 
(everything in production section will be inherited by testing and development section):

```
[production]
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

[testing : production]
bootstrap.class = "productionBootstrap"

[development : production]
bootstrap.class = "developmentBootstrap"
```

**XML config example** 
(everything in production section will be inherited by staging section, note extends keyword):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configdata>
    <production>
        <webhost>www.example.com</webhost>
        <database>
            <adapter>pdo_mysql</adapter>
            <params>
                <host>db.example.com</host>
                <username>dbuser</username>
                <password>secret</password>
                <dbname>dbname</dbname>
            </params>
        </database>
    </production>
    <staging extends="production">
        <database>
            <params>
                <host>dev.example.com</host>
                <username>devuser</username>
                <password>devsecret</password>
            </params>
        </database>
    </staging>
</configdata>
```

**PHP config example** 
No inheritance/nesting?
Is there a way to make inheritance/nesting work without doing manual array merging?

```
return array(
    'production' => array(
         $test1 => 'aaaaaaa'
     ),
    'staging' => array(
        $test2 => 'bbbbbb'
    ),
    'testing' => array(
        $test3 => 'bbbbbb'
    )

)
```

**UPDATE**

In retrospect - just wanted to add that there are certain advantages to using php arrays instead of ini files for configuration:
[some info](http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2009/05/08/writing-powerful-and-easy-config-files-with-php-arrays)

· they can be cached by an opcode cache

· they support constants

· they allow to create easily readable config trees

· they support boolean and integer values

Comment: Why would you prefer to use it? The Zend Framework comes with an excellent configuration implementation both for ini and for xml files.

Comment: well IMHO 1) i don't think php is so much more complex than raw.ini 2) it's easier to handle booleans for example - in ini everything is string. 3) it's the fastest way to get variables.

Comment: Why the downvote? Downvoter - care to explain negative vote plz?

Comment: 1/ Maybe not, but your asking for the wheel to be reinvented. Its not that simple, otherwise you wouldn't be here, you'd be getting on with using `.ini` 2/ In PHP nothing is strongly typed so that doesn't make sense

Comment: could you please clarifiy what you are looking for in a solution. Do you want to convert from .ini to another format or do you want to know how to parse such a block?

Comment: @Gordon - i've updated the question. maybe it'll be more clear :)

Comment: @Andre thanks for the update. ArneRie's suggestion below looks useful to me as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iam not sure what you mean, but you can simulate this in your php file with your config like this:

```
$configProduction = array(
    'database' => $db1,
    'url'      => 'www.production.com',
);

$configDevelopment = array(
    'url' => 'www.test.com',
);

//ENV is set in bootstrap or htaccess or php.ini
switch (APPLICATION_ENV) {
    case 'production':
        $config = $configProduction;
        break;
    case 'development':
        $config = array_merge($configProduction, $configDevelopment);
        break;
}
```

Comment: that should probably be `array_merge_recursive` to allow overwriting of keys in subarrays as well.

Comment: For example, [DASPRiD](http://twitter.com/dasprid) uses `array_merge_recursive()` in [his blog application](http://site.svn.dasprids.de/trunk/application/config/config.php).

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't sure if Zend_Application handles array keys merging based on environment. But after looking through the code  - it doesn't. Thanks for this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch to support scalars in `Zend_Config`.

See

- [ZF-2312 - Automatic primitive type detection for Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2312)

The patch wasn't accepted into trunk for a number of reasons, so there is no guarantee there won't be any side-effects. The patch is also rather old, so it might need some adjustment to make this work with recent versions of `Zend_Config`.

For getting an idea on how to approach the issue, it might be helpful though.